# Tex live 64 bit and Windows

Tags: texlive, windows, texlive2022

According to https://tug.org/texlive/windows.html , Tex live on Windows has yet to support 64 bit. It is expected migrate to 64 bit next year. Then,

1. Are all packages on Unix and Mac already 64 bit?
2. Are there noticeable time saves in using 64 bit instead of 32 bit?
3. Will every single package need to be updated when their 64 bit counterparts are released?
4. Will any code changes be needed for the change in version?

Comment: If by "packages" you mean `.sty` files loaded with `\usepackage`, then packages are just TeX code, their functionality does not depend on the type of system you use.

Comment: win64 v win32  is for most tex purposes just an invisible implementation detail, it does not affect tex code at all.